# Does dependency injection in ASP.NET Core add performance overhead?

Tags: asp.net-core, design-patterns

I'm working on a app where DI was avoided to improve performance. The service dependency is implemented as a static class and referenced directly in the calling class. This is presenting the typical challenges for testing since it's not possible in inject a stub for this service.

My first thought is to setup a regular class and interface, put it into the container as a singleton, and then inject it into the calling class constructor. This API app is very performance critical, so the design choices cannot add any extra milliseconds to the response time.

Is it possible to use DI without adding some performance overhead? If not, is there another design pattern I can use to maintain performance but improve the testability of the class at the same time?

Comment: That said, please read: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: The app is using .NET 5.

Comment: So use the correct tags then, please. ASP.NET Web API died with ASP.NET Framework.

Comment: ASP.NET Core uses DI for resolving hundreds of internal services (like Controllers, middleware, serializers, etc etc), so it's not like adding your services to DI would be starting from scratch. Best you can do is just give it a test.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That insight about internal use of DI in ASP.NET is very helpful. I did not know about that. I saw the tag for asp.net-core but since Microsoft is dropping the "core" and I'm on 5, I hesitated. I'm feeling much better about using a standard DI approach now. I'm going to write some benchmark tests and post the results back here.

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft completely screwed up names.... .NET Framework -> old, .NET Core -> 1.0-3.1, .NET -> 5.0+. However, ASP.NET -> old, ASP.NET Core -> new (regardless of .NET Framework, .NET Core or .NET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a simple test to verify this and found that using a Singleton service from DI did not add any significant overhead to the performance.

I created a simple service with an interface and registered it in the services collection. I created 2 controllers. In one I used new Service() to get the instance and in the other I injected it through in constructor.

I started the app in Release build mode and ran load tests on each controller using K6. The controller that uses new Service() averaged 184.94 microseconds and the one that used injection averaged 186.07 microseconds.

So using DI did add a slight (1 millionth of a second) overhead. That may be small enough to be unnoticeable in using the API.